# Validating possibilities for HashMap access

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Im asking myself what could be the more elegant way of validating a HashMap access.

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();

if(m.hasNext()){
    ...}
else
    System.out.println("Error.");
```

or

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();

try{
    m.getNext();
catch(Exception e){
        ...}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: There is no method like `m.hasNext()` in a HashMap - are you referring to an Iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A test is always preferable to exceptions.